# Writing professional texts

Tags: color-theory, information-graphics, paragraph-styles

Since I don't know pretty much about, I'd like to ask you:

- What makes a text professional?
- At first glance, what do people notice in the text that will then prompt them to read it?
- What colors can I use to make a scientific report more engaging but professional at the same time?
- How many images should I enter on average for the photographic memory to activate?

thanks for the attentions.

Comment: What's your audience? Some of the most important scientific papers were handwritten - https://www.spbooks.com/95-la-theorie-de-la-relativite-generale-9791095457053.html

Comment: "What makes a text professional?" Content. "How many images should I enter" as many good images as you can make, however lousy images are just a dsitraction.

Comment: those who read this text will not be able to understand exactly data and statistics because they are maintenance workers;
so I have to make the text really understandable and readable.
So my question is:
How can I get many people interested in a scientific text at first sight?
the text serves to inform them of what, technically speaking, they are doing without realizing it on the assembly line; a sort of company magazine

Comment: @MrX that does not actually change anything all content is written for the audience in hand. Also never say they dont understand youd be suprised how smart some poeple are regardless of what they do

Comment: @joojaa my idea is not to question the cognitive faculties of the audience, but to write things in the most practical and consistent way possible... thanks for all your helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About colors

**Highly saturated** or high intensity colors (a pure color with no other mixed colors) or highly detailed areas are **used to attract attention**, and thus give the impression of carrying more weight than less saturated, *low intensity areas* or visually simpler.

But, don't overdo it - less is better.
With color schemes, it's a good choice to limit your creative explorations.
Therefore I recommend that you stick to **two or three color combinations** - or, of course, use a single color.

You can use some ideas like :

- **Black or Brown and Orange:**
  It transmit a sense of Lively and powerful
- **Brownish and cyan:**
  To transmit a Serene and reliable state, like a comfortable zone

If you want to use three colors an idea could be:

- **Dark blue, turquoise and beige:**
  To give a Confident and creative idea to your file.

### The text

Use simple and clear sentences.
Where the *important things are at the **top***, **summarized** in the **first three sentences**.

The inflection of the voice is where there is a **bold**, to underline a **word or an entire phrase**.
And punctuation is essential for catching a breath, breathing between one term and another.

### People are attracted from the design of the page

Pages are designed by paragraphs, white spaces, buttons and links.
Insert **bullets**, play with different **font sizes** (remember less is better) of titles and subtitles,
add embedded images or videos, *italics*, question marks or dots and that's it.
Put as many image as you want, to explain the ideas, not to confuse the reader!

But most of all the colors evoke emotions and these emotions are somehow connected to the product.
They play a **"subconscious" role** and are able **to stimulate actions and reactions** by creating in people the need to *"move" in the desired direction*.